# Can I use a BlendState object to emulate a draw call's blending color?

Tags: xna, alpha-blending

I'm working on a lighting system for a tile-based game.

What I want to do is draw my tiles to the screen, then draw a single Texture2D object (my light map) over top of them. However, doing it in two steps results in the tiles looking "painted" and washed out.

To get this effect working, I called `Texture2D.GetData()` and then used that `Color` as the blending color when calling `SpriteBatch.Draw()` on each tile, which results in them being "tinted" correctly. This works, but it's a fair bit slower, and won't scale up for huge maps/view areas.

So, is it possible to use a BlendState object to do what I am doing above?

- [Tile map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN2pm.png)
- [Light map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INktm.png)
- [Tile map with light map applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAR5J.png) (per tile)

Comment: Additive blending should do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've tried all of the built-in BlendState objects, but they don't produce the results I'm trying for. In the third image, the areas that aren't lit up end up black - if I used additive blending, then Black (0,0,0) wouldn't affect the final image, and it just ends up looking like pic related: http://i.imgur.com/DVrKnW4.png

Comment: Turns out I did need additive blending, but also to adjust a few other blend settings too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution I was looking for.
Since my light map used transparency, I simply used:

```
ColorSourceBlend = Blend.Zero;
ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha;
ColorBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add;
```

Had to adjust a few things to support it, but it works great.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted, so other users can see at a glance through the search results that the problem is solved.